# Rescaling of cosine families

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, semigroups-of-operators

First of all, the best wishes for 2024. Recently, I got aware of cosine operator families (in the framework of evolution equations). It is well-known, that operator semigroups can be rescaled (see for example Engel-Nagel). The question I have, if there is anything like this for cosine families. Is it possible to rescale cosine operator families, and if if how?

Best wishes to all of you.

Comment: How do you mean rescaling?